# Нужны ли запятые при словах "и по совместительству"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Они самые старые(,) и по совместительству(,) самые ...**

Comment: Обычно люди работают по совместительству или совмещают должности. Здесь переносное значение? А как в этом случае можно проверить предложение, если представлено только его начало? Смысл абсолютно неясен, и возникает вопрос: неужели трудно написать весь текст или хотя бы его основную часть?

Answer (score 1):

Словосочетание "и по совместительству" широко употребляется как в прямом смысле(совмещение должностей), так и в переносном. Анализ примеров из Нацкорпуса показывает, что в подавляющем большинстве случаев нет знаков препинания при этом выражении. Думаю, отдельные исключения из правила можно отнести к авторским или интонационным.

> Гендиректор **и по совместительству** тренер «Спартака» Валерий Карпин вообще не заметил никакого фола, а по поводу травмы Акинфеева заявил, что это его проблемы. [Александр Кобеляцкий. Нога Акинфеева // «Русский репортер», № 34 (212), 1 сентября 2011, 2011]
>
> Друг **и по совместительству** сосед ― меркантильный Алексей Лебедев ― ехидно поинтересовался ценой тренажёра. [Александр Зильберт. Укрепление тонуса (1997) // «Столица», 1997.03.18]
>
> Владелец одной из городских металлоломных компаний **и по совместительству** сын главы клана Кармине Аньелло безвозмездно передал коммунальщикам принадлежащий ему промышленный измельчитель, способный «жевать» стальные балки, стоимостью 6 млн долларов. [Николай Анищенко. Мафия на службе народа // «Русский репортер», 2014]
>
> Появились и «борцы за независимость» ― защитники крестьян от ненавистных «колонизаторов» **и, по совместительству,** разбойники. [Юрий Бондарь. Финка: «воровской» стиль // «Криминальный отдел», 2010]
>
> [Дегустатор, муж] Чего стоит хотя бы один местный шаромыга **и по совместительству** пьяница дед Митя (хотя он, конечно, на деда не очень-то и похож). [коллективный. Форум: Любовь и голуби (2007-2011)]

Answer (score 1):

**Они самые старые, и по совместительству, самые ...**

1) ***По совместительству*** ― наречие (наречное выражение). Как и другие наречия,  оно обычно не обособляется, что видно из приведенных  у М.Г. примеров, но при определенных условиях может быть обособлено **с целью выделения.**

Для этого наречие должно "выпадать" из структуры предложения, **именно этот случай возможен в заданном примере** (но для окончательного решения нужен контекст).

Обратим внимание на то, что здесь наречие относится **к прилагательному**, в то время как во всех других примерах оно стоит перед существительным.

Кстати, в предложении  "...**защитники крестьян от ненавистных «колонизаторов» и, по совместительству, разбойники**" обособление скорее делается по грамматическому принципу, так как интонационно это сложно выразить.

Comment: Допустим, хотим обособить "по совместительству". Но почему запятая перед И, а не после него?